# How to replace blank cells in a DataTable column with the value of the cell above

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to replace the blank cells in specific column in a DataTable with the value of the cell above it?

For example, I have the following DataTable:

```
--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
            |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
            |  Black
            |  White
--------------------
```

And it should be like to the following table:

```
--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
   00A0B    |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
   00A0C    |  Black
   00A0C    |  White
--------------------
```

So how can I do that? I need to have very efficient method as the amount of data could be big.

Comment: what if first row is empty?

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want, but of course for the first empty items (while you haven't got to a row with a product code yet), it will set empty string:

```
string code = "", nonEmpty = "";
foreach(var row in datatable.Rows)
{
    code = row["ProductCode"].ToString();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
         nonEmpty = code;
    else
        row["ProductCode"] = nonEmpty;  
}
```

However you may set a default value for `nonEmpty` so that if there are rows with empty `ProductCode` in the begining, set them with the default value. then the first line of code should be like:

```
string code = "", nonEmpty = "DefaultPC";
```